# See which files were not committed using VSS

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I would like to know if there is a way of figuring out which files in a folder were not committed in VSS 8.0.xxxxx.

Any feature in VSS 8.0.xxxxx to achieve this?

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [diff](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe/project-diff.html) the local folder with the server copy to achieve this.